# Resolve Host's IP on VM

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, hostname, hosts

I have kind of tricky situation. I have monitoring tool where all my hosts and their VM's (with IP's and so on) are listed. But what I need is to resolve on which host(need it's ip or hostname) this monitoring tool is because tool does not list itself. I know that the main point of virtualization is to not show that but maybe there is any way to get any info when connected to *VM* about it's ***host***?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do this. This is not a question of intent but of *nature*: The creators of virtual machine managers do not merely *want* to hide the host's IP, the very nature of the host/guest relationship creates an impenetrable barrier between these two systems. Short of bugs or other implementation problems, you aren't going to be able to pierce this barrier.

I suggest that you add an entry to `/etc/hosts` for the host's IP:

```
1.2.3.4    HOST_IP
```

Then your monitoring tool can just refer to `HOST_IP` generically.

Naturally, if the host system's IP changes, you will have to change all of the guests' `/etc/hosts` files. This also adds a step in VM migration.

Comment: Hmm, maybe my question was not clear but thanks for info. I just dont want to do manual search because there are many hosts and this tool can be anywhere. I just need host's hostname or ip..

Comment: I mean host's on which my tool is built.

Comment: I thought you wanted each VM to know it's host machine's IP address based on the last sentence of your question. Are we talking about a third machine here? That is, the VM, its host, and some other monitoring machine?

Comment: Hosts and VMs (monitoring tool as a virtual machine), I guess.. Thats why I need to know its host to understand if it is under same hosts or is it third machine which monitors all the others.